# How do I extract a value from a JSON response?

Tags: ruby, json

I am writing some tests in Ruby using RestClient. The test is working fine and the response is in JSON however when I parse the JSON and try to extract the values I am looking for I get an error saying `IndexError: key not found`

IMO, my code should work. The JSON is:

```
{"user":{"@xmlns":{"dvi":"http:\/\/xxxx","a":"http:\/\/xxxx","$":"http:\/\/xxxx"},"link":[{"@rel":"self","$":"http:\/\/xxxx"},{"@rel":"user","$":"http:\/\/xxxx"},{"@rel":"usage","$":"xxxx"},{"@rel":"repositories","$":"http:\/\/xxxx"},{"@rel":"shares","$":"http:\/\/xxxx"},{"@rel":"shareMemberships","$":"http:\/\/xxxx"}],"phone":{"$":"3518012343001"},"email":{"$":""},"firstName":{"$":"Jim"},"lastName":{"$":"Joe"},"uid":{"$":"91bc7a72bc724e5e9b53e688dd105ed4"},"accountName":{"$":"3518012343001"},"notificationMethod":{"$":"email sms"},"accountStatus":{"$":"Active"},"serviceLevel":{"$":"5"},"repositoryCount":{"$":"1"},"usage":{"allowed":{"$":"5368709120"},"total":{"$":"1024"}},"contactEmail":{"$":"jim@joe.com"}}}
```

and my code is:

```
result = jsonabove
jdoc = JSON.parse(result)
notificationMethod = jdoc.fetch("notificationMethod")

return notificationMethod
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's happening because the `notificationMethod` key isn't the first level key in your hash. After preparing the`JSON#parse` method, you have a hash with only one key called `user`. You should get the value by this key and then apply your `notificationMethod` key. It looks like this:

```
require 'json'

result = <<HERE
{"user":{"......"}}
HERE

jdoc = JSON.parse(result)
notificationMethod = jdoc.fetch("user").fetch("notificationMethod")
puts notificationMethod
```

Comment: Not at all, glad to help you!